# WPF window/usercontrol inheritance XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, tabcontrol

I'm implementing an editor for a game and ran across a slight inconvience I can't seem to figure out. My Google-fu is also failing on me to find an answer whether or not what I want is even possible.

My editor basically has a detail-window for each object it manages, this detail window is always the same: a tab-control, with on Tab called "Properties", and 1 or more tabs specific to the object the window is for.

I figured it would be nice to have a BaseEditor.xaml which has the TabControl with the Properties-tab defined, from which you can extend and add more tabs as you please.

I've tried multiple solution, one by making a UserControl, adding a TabControl on it, then add a CompositeCollection to it, which is bound to a property in the code-behind, which I can then technically modify when I add the usercontrol to a window. However, it doesn't work in the slightest, and I'm also not happy with the fact I have to add the UserControl to a Window, rather than extend from a Window.

All in all, here's my first attempt:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
            <TabControl.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding TabItems}" />
                    <TabItem Header="Properties" />
                </CompositeCollection>
            </TabControl.ItemsSource>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then on the Window it's used like this:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <UserControl>
            <UserControl.TabItems>
                <TabItem Header="Test" />
            <UserControl.TabItems>
        </UserControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is pseudo-code, but as said, it doesn't work, it will just show the properties-tab and that's it.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making a TabControl which you register tabs to on demand (eg. by means of a `RegisterTab`-method, rather than trying to define it through XAML.